# Diagonalizability of a certain matrix in $\mathbb{Z}_5$

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

True/False: Matrix $\ \begin{pmatrix}1&3\\3&4\end{pmatrix}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is diagonalizable.

I have come to the conclusion that all the Eigenvectors for this matrix are not linearly independent, therefore it is not diagonalizable; however, I am not sure if my conclusion is correct. Would you be able to assist me in confirming my results?
Thank you!

P.S. I also see that this matrix is symmetric, which should mean that it is diagonalizable, but maybe not in Zmod5?

Comment: In fact [Any Nilpotent Matrix is not Diagonalizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1820350/399263). Here we have $A^2=0$ and $A\neq 0$ so it is nilpotent.

Answer (score 2):

It's not diagonalizable. Clearly both of its determinant and trace are zero. Therefore, it has only $0$ as its eigenvalue. If it's diagonalizable, then it would be similar to and hence must be the zero matrix itself.

Symmetric matrices can be diagonalized is a theorem that holds only over the real numbers. It's not even true over $\mathbb C$ (instead, conjugate symmetric matrices over $\mathbb C$ can be diagonalized). In fact, there are two types of theorems in linear algebra: those that are purely algebraic and hence works over almost any field, and others that use some kind of analysis such as positivity in reals. [The spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) belongs to the latter class.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helps!

Comment: So, is the matrix nilpotent over $\mathbb{Z}_5$? Square the matrix (over $\mathbb{Z}$) and see whether you get a matrix with all its entries being divisible by $5$.

Comment: You can use Cayley-Hamilton to conclude it's nilpotent, or simply it has only zero eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0):

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&3\\3&4\end{pmatrix}$

Characteristics polynomial : $\begin{align}\chi_A(t) &=t^2-5t-5\in \mathbb{Z}_5[t]\\&=t^2\end{align}$

Hence $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ of multiplicity (algebraic) $2$.

But geometric multiplicity of $0$ is $1$ (shortage of independent eigenvectors )
i.e $\dim E(0, A) =\dim\mathcal{N}(A) =1$

$\begin{pmatrix} 1&3\\3&4\end{pmatrix}\overset{R_2-3R_1}\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 1&3\\0&-5\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 1&3\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Conclusion: $A$ is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb{Z}_5$